# MOSS ItemStyle.xsl

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt, 2007

I have a content query webpart which uses a style within ItemStyle.xsl. How can I  extract the URL that the webpart sits within from ItemStyle.xsl?

Many Thanks, Nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check the below article and see if this solves your problem

http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/sharepoint-referencing-the-current-site-url-in-a-data-view-web-part/